# Anomalous Spectral Function and STM

Tags: greens-functions, microscopy

I have a question in regard to the anomalous spectral function and how it pertains to STM experiments. The use of the spectral representation of Green functions is assumed known, so I do not go into those details.

When the tip is superconducting (SC), Cooper pairs can tunnel, which gives additional information to the SC properties of the sample. STM traditionally uses a normal metal with a constant density-of-states (DOS) around the Fermi energy, so that we can measure the local-DOS (LDOS) of the sample. This comes from the following relation:
$$
        I_s 
        =
        2\pi e
        |\Gamma|^2
        \int
        d\omega
        \big[f(\omega)-f(\omega-eV)\big]
        L_s(\omega)
        L_t(\omega-eV)
$$
With $s$ and $t$ standing for sample and tip, and the $L$'s are LDOS. We take $L_t(\omega)\approx constant$, with the zero of energy being the Fermi energy. $\textbf{Being able to factor out the tips LDOS allows one to determine local properties of the}$ $\textbf{sample!}$

In the case of Cooper pair tunneling, we have a more complicated expression for the current, which I will neglect here. It will involve the anomalous Green function opposed to the normal one, and we can express this guy using the spectral representation as well. It's form is, assuming we posses a BdG Hamiltonian and we defined the usual canonical transforms ($\hat{c}_{i\uparrow }= v^*_{il}\hat{b}_{l}^\dagger
    +u_{il}\hat{b}_{l}$, etc.), as follows (using Temperature Green function):
$$
    F_{i}^T(i\tilde{\omega}_n)
    =
    -\frac{1}{\beta}
    \int_0^\beta d\tau\;
   \langle{T_\tau\big(
    \hat{c}_{i\sigma}(\tau)
    \hat{c}_{i\sigma}
    \big)}\rangle
    \\
    =
    -\frac{1}{\beta}
    \int d\omega 
    \frac{1}{i\tilde{\omega}_n-\omega}
    \sum_{E_l\geq 0}
    u_{il}v^*_{il}
    \Big(
    \delta(\omega+E_l)
    +
    \delta(\omega-E_l)
    \Big)
    \\
    =
    -\frac{1}{\beta}
    \int d\omega 
    \frac{A(\omega)}{i\tilde{\omega}_n-\omega}
$$
We'd need to do a few more steps to describe the response, like analytically continue the frequency to get the retarded Green function, but those details are not important. We end up with an integral over products of expressions like: $$\iint d\omega d\omega' (\dots)A_s(\omega)A^*_t(\omega')$$
$\textbf{Are there any SC with a constant anomalous spectral function around the Fermi energy,}$ $\textbf{so that we can take this piece outside the integral like we did with the single particle}$ $\textbf{current?}$

Any insight is appreciated! Is there a way to see this in terms of the gap as well? The combination $\sum uv^*$ is related to the self consistent gap equation, so I am guessing so.

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.